# Converting a string to a set of array with fixed length

Tags: php, string, optimization

I need to convert a string into a set of arrays of a fixed length.

Example: input: `1111122222333333`

I need output of

```
[0] =>
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
[1] =>
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 2
    [4] => 2
```

The following code works great:

```
    for ($x = 0; $x < count($codedDataArray) - $colWidthSum + 1; $x += $colWidthSum + 1) {

        for ($c = 0; $c <= $colWidthSum; $c++) {
            $rows[$j][] = $codedDataArray[$z];
            $z++;
        }
        $j++;
    }
```

but it runs out of memory when I give it really large strings, say 10959 bytes.

Is there a built-in PHP function I'm missing that will do the same thing, or am I just going to have to deal with the memory issues?

EDIT 1: I'm running out of memory on both `preg_split` and `str_split` as well, so I'm probably doing something really wrong. I'll still mark as answered, as soon as I figure out what my initial issue was in the first place.

EDIT 2: The string length is actually 745,982 bytes, I was looking at the compressed length.

EDIT 3: I think the string is just too big. I'll have to see if there as a way of breaking it up without losing data since that's actually a small example and it's actually binary data. Thanks for the answers everyone!

Comment: Runs out of memory or infinite loop?

Comment: runs out of memory. Works find on a stream of length 137, so I don't think it's a loop.

Comment: Doesn't seem like it should with a 11k string...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try this.  I've just tested with a string of 10,000 words and it didn't run out of memory:

```
$array = str_split($string);

// returns $array = Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 1
    [4] => 1
    [5] => 2
    [6] => 2
    [7] => 2
    [8] => 2
    [9] => 2
    [10] => 3
    [11] => 3
   // and so on
)
```

Then:

```
array_chunk($array, 5);

// returns:

[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => 1
        [3] => 1
        [4] => 1
    )

[1] => Array
  (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 2
        [3] => 2
        [4] => 2
    )
```

Answer (score 3):

The [str_split](http://php.net/manual/function.str-split.php) function might help you, but you'll have to handle the last chunk yourself.

Comment: That looked promising, but that runs out of memory as well.

Comment: To be more specific, your sample output needs two splits, you can get it with something like `array_map ('str_split', str_split ($str, $length))`.

If if runs out of memory, then you may want to raise your PHP "max_memory" limit setting.

Answer (score 1):

Use something like

```
$str = '1111122222333333';
$result = array_chunk(str_split($str), 5);
print_r($result);
```

Anyways, one way to handle out-of-memory errors can be the creation of a php script that only imlements your internal "for loop" and then call an [PHP exec](http://php.net/manual/function.exec.php) inside the biggest loop.

This will cause the process to launch a thread for each "looping job" without overflowing the memory

Comment: I think I may have to go the php exec route unless I can figure out what is causing the modem issues. I could expand the max memory, but that just means I'm willing to accept I have poor code.

Comment: This is a poor use of `preg_split()` as you don't need the regular expression. `str_split()` does the same thing in this case and would be better performing. It was already suggested by **Damien Pirsy**.

Answer (score 1):

You're not missing something, this is not something built-in. PHP is great at parsing strings, but it can have difficulties with large inputs.

If you know the length of the chunks (and it looks like you do):

```
// Breaks the strink into $chunkLength sized pieces.
$arr = str_split($input, $chunkLenght);
// str_split all of the chunks:
// explode technically is more historic, but str_split is easier.
array_walk($arr, 'str_split');
```

If you don't know the chunk size, you'll need to figure that out:

```
$sizes = array();
$current = FALSE;
$len = count($input);
$curCount = 0;

for($i = 0; $ < $len; $i++){
    if($current != $input[$i]) {
        $current = $input[$i];
        $sizes[$current] = $curCount;
        $curCount = 0;
    }
    $curCount++;
}

function get_filled_array($num, $count) {
     return arrat_pad(array(), $count, $num);
}
$output = array();

foreach($sizes as $index => $count) {
    $output[$index] = get_filled_array($index, $count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Push substrings to the array

```
$result = array();
for ($index=0; $index<=strlen($string)-$width; $index+= $width)
{
array_push($result,substr($string,$index,$width));
}
```